# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project daily-installer:

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am getting permission denied error. I have given permission to the folder as well. I have checked all over in Stack Overflow and nothing seems to be working. When I close and open Eclipse it works on Eclipse. The environment that I am using is Ubuntu 18.

```html
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building daily-installer 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[WARNING] The artifact org.apache.commons:commons-io:jar:1.3.2 has been relocated to commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ daily-installer ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/yellowfin/Downloads/story-master/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ daily-installer ---

[WARNING] Attempt to (de-)serialize anonymous class hudson.maven.reporters.MavenArtifactArchiver$2; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/serialization-of-anonymous-classes/
[WARNING] Attempt to (de-)serialize anonymous class hudson.maven.reporters.MavenFingerprinter$1; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/serialization-of-anonymous-classes/
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.964 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-03T12:30:58+10:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/399M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project daily-installer: Error while storing the mojo status: /home/yellowfin/Downloads/story-master/target/maven-status/maven-compiler-plugin/compile/default-compile/inputFiles.lst (Permission denied) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[JENKINS] Archiving /home/yellowfin/Downloads/story-master/pom.xml to com.yellowfin.installer/daily-installer/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/daily-installer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
/home/yellowfin/Downloads/story-master/pom.xml is not inside /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Story Regression Automation/home/yellowfin/Downloads/story-master/; will archive in a separate pass
channel stopped
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Story Regression Automation/home/yellowfin/Downloads/story-master/pom.xml
 at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
 at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
 at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
 at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
 at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
 at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
 at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:384)
 at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152)
 at hudson.FilePath.read(FilePath.java:1973)
 at jenkins.plugins.maveninfo.extractor.properties.PomPropertiesFinder.findProperties(PomPropertiesFinder.java:50)
 at jenkins.plugins.maveninfo.extractor.MavenInfoExtractor.extract(MavenInfoExtractor.java:58)
 at jenkins.plugins.maveninfo.extractor.MavenInfoEnvironment.tearDown(MavenInfoEnvironment.java:42)
 at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:908)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
 at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1815)
 at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
 at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
 at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)

Finished: FAILURE
```

### Update

I have given permission again and now I am getting the following error

```html
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building daily-installer 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The artifact org.apache.commons:commons-io:jar:1.3.2 has been relocated to commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ daily-installer ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/yellowfin/Downloads/story-master/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ daily-installer ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 10 source files to /home/yellowfin/Downloads/story-master/target/classes
[WARNING] Attempt to (de-)serialize anonymous class hudson.maven.reporters.MavenArtifactArchiver$2; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/serialization-of-anonymous-classes/
[WARNING] Attempt to (de-)serialize anonymous class hudson.maven.reporters.MavenFingerprinter$1; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/serialization-of-anonymous-classes/
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.915 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-03T13:59:12+10:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/398M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project daily-installer: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[JENKINS] Archiving /home/yellowfin/Downloads/story-master/pom.xml to com.yellowfin.installer/daily-installer/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/daily-installer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
/home/yellowfin/Downloads/story-master/pom.xml is not inside /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Story Regression Automation/home/yellowfin/Downloads/story-master/; will archive in a separate pass
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Story Regression Automation/home/yellowfin/Downloads/story-master/pom.xml
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
 at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
 at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
 at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
 at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
 at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
 at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
 at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:384)
 at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152)
 at hudson.FilePath.read(FilePath.java:1973)
 at jenkins.plugins.maveninfo.extractor.properties.PomPropertiesFinder.findProperties(PomPropertiesFinder.java:50)
 at jenkins.plugins.maveninfo.extractor.MavenInfoExtractor.extract(MavenInfoExtractor.java:58)
 at jenkins.plugins.maveninfo.extractor.MavenInfoEnvironment.tearDown(MavenInfoEnvironment.java:42)
 at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:908)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
 at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1815)
 at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
 at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
 at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE
```

when I run mvn clean it is displaying permission error again. I am not sure how to address this problem.

Please see the folder structure below

[image]

Here is my Jenkins screenshot. Thanks
[image]

Now I am getting the following error

```html
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The artifact org.apache.commons:commons-io:jar:1.3.2 has been relocated to commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ daily-installer ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/yellowfin/Downloads/story-master/target
[WARNING] Attempt to (de-)serialize anonymous class hudson.maven.reporters.MavenArtifactArchiver$2; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/serialization-of-anonymous-classes/
[WARNING] Attempt to (de-)serialize anonymous class hudson.maven.reporters.MavenFingerprinter$1; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/serialization-of-anonymous-classes/
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.570 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-04T08:49:09+10:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/399M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) on project daily-installer: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete /home/yellowfin/Downloads/story-master/target/test-classes/Yellowfin/bi/qa/testcases/TimelinePageTest.class -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[JENKINS] Archiving /home/yellowfin/Downloads/story-master/pom.xml to com.yellowfin.installer/daily-installer/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/daily-installer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
/home/yellowfin/Downloads/story-master/pom.xml is not inside /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Story Regression Automation/home/yellowfin/Downloads/story-master/; will archive in a separate pass
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Story Regression Automation/home/yellowfin/Downloads/story-master/pom.xml
 at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
 at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
 at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
 at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
 at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
 at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
 at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:384)
 at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152)
 at hudson.FilePath.read(FilePath.java:1973)
 at jenkins.plugins.maveninfo.extractor.properties.PomPropertiesFinder.findProperties(PomPropertiesFinder.java:50)
 at jenkins.plugins.maveninfo.extractor.MavenInfoExtractor.extract(MavenInfoExtractor.java:58)
 at jenkins.plugins.maveninfo.extractor.MavenInfoEnvironment.tearDown(MavenInfoEnvironment.java:42)
 at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:908)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
 at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1815)
 at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
 at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
 at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show me the project structure, want to know location of `pom.xml`?

Comment: Please see the above screenshot for project structure. Thanks

Comment: Can you show me the Build step of Jenkins Job?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @Arpit please see the Jenkins build step. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Story Regression Automation` is the name of a Jenkins Job which builds `Story-Automation` project picking it either from Disk or and any Version Control tool, **Root POM** location of the **Build step** should be `pom.xml` and not `/home/yellowfin/Downloads/story-master/pom.xml`

Comment: I changed to it just to pom.xml. Now I am getting the No such file error. Please see the screenshot above

Comment: Can you show me `Source Code Management` step of the Jenkins Job?

Comment: Please see the screenshot above. Thanks

Comment: @BobJones Can you clone the project `Story-Automation` in directory `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/` and in the `Build Step` change the `Root POM` location to `pom.xml`

Comment: Please see above screen shot for the error. I am trying to execute using maven in linux and I am getting the same compilation error

Comment: @BobJones jenkins is building your project, it's compilation error in your code, fix them and build will be success.

Comment: The same tests work on my local pc which has jenkins installed on it. However when I try to run these tests in the remote machine it does not work, I have tried to update the compiler plugin, re-installed java and updated the environment variables and nothing has fixed it. I am not sure which compilation code I need to fix.